# Spring autowired difference between class field and method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring framework, and try to figure out what is the difference between spring autowired at class's field and class's method, like below's IUtil and IUserDao:

> ```
> @Controller
> @RequestMapping("/user")
> public class UserController{
>
>     @Autowired
>     private IUtil util;
>
>     private IUserDao userDao;
>     
>     @Autowired
>     public UserController(IUserDao dao){
>         this.userDao = dao;
>     }
>
>     ...
>     ...
>     ...
> }
> ```

IUtil is inject by field, and IUserDao is inject by constructor, what's the difference between them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in case of constructor DI you may keep beans immutable and "easily" construct bean instances without using DI framework - some developers insist that is useful in unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "time point" of injection is different;

Consider the following code：

```
public class Index {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext AcContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfigration.class);
    }
}

@Configuration
class MyConfigration {
    @Bean
    public UserController userController() { return new UserController(); }
    @Bean
    public IUtil util() { return new Util(); }
    @Bean
    public IUserDao userDao() { return new UserDao(); }
}

interface IUtil {
    public String getDate();
}
interface IUserDao {}

class Util implements IUtil {
    public String date = "2023-06-26";
    @Override
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
class UserDao implements IUserDao {}

class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private IUtil util;
    private String date;

    public UserController(){
        this.date = util.getDate();
    }
}
```

Think about it, execute this code, what will happen?

The answer is that a null pointer exception will occur when `this.date = util.getDate();`

Because when injecting through the properties of the class, it is after the class is instantiated.

Going back to your example, in your example, in your UserController initialization, you can do something with userDao, but in initialization you cannot use util

Comment: Friends who voted against, don't you give your own answer? 
Or point out what's wrong with my answer in the comments?If there are any mistakes in the answer, look forward to correcting

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness explanation, my friend. Thanks~